# ¿Cómo leo texto y lo voy acumulando hasta que se escriba un carácter determinado?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Quiero hacer un programa que fuera leyendo cadenas textos y que la fuera guardando, hasta que el usuario pusiera un '.' y detuviera la aplicación sacando lo escrito por pantalla.

De momento la idea de pedir por pantalla y que se detenga el programa al ingresar un punto, lo tengo claro.
No obstante no consigo ver cómo hacer que se guarde lo escrito en disco para que luego se muestre.

Adjunto el código y una imagen para que su visionado sea lo mejor posible.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    read -p "Dame un texto" punto
    case $punto in
        [.]* ) exit;;
    esac
done
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres guardarlo en disco, busca en un archivo. Tengo esta propuesta usando una implementación de un `do-while`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ARCHIVO="./archivo.txt"

guardar() {
    if [[ "$1" != . ]]; then
        printf "$1" >> "$ARCHIVO"
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

while 
    read -p "Dame un texto: " _input
    guardar "$_input"
do
    :
done

echo "Texto acumulado:"
cat "$ARCHIVO"
```

Y todo se encuentra almacenado dentro del archivo `archivo.txt`:

El programa termina si el usuario ingresa solo un punto. Puede ingresar varios y el programa va a continuar; pero si ingresa solo uno, la función devuelve un estado de 1 (como un error).

[Aquí tienes](https://gitlab.com/mrc_es/stackoverflow_answers/-/blob/master/bash/461011/main) la misma respuesta en mi repositorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente ve acumulando los datos en una variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
texto=""
while true; do
    read -p "Dame un texto " punto
    case $punto in
        [.]* ) break;;
    esac
    texto="$texto $punto"
done

echo "texto final: $texto"
```

Fíjate que en lugar de `exit`, pongo `break` para que salga del bucle `while`. Así se ejecutará el comando final de `echo "texto final: $texto"`.

Comment: Tienes razón, me ha funcionado perfecto, ¡Muchas gracias!